# Is there a way to isolate bacteria from a bacteria/phage plaque in order to PCR bacteria only?

Tags: bacteriology, pcr, protocol, bacteriophage

I am writing a paper for a class that involves a mock grant proposal. I am looking at an experiment which requires sequencing of host DNA from a virus/host model, and am having a hard time finding a protocol which keeps bacteria as opposed to phage. From what I'm seeing, my two options for separating the phage and bacteria are either centrifuging or filtration, neither of which keeps the bacteria. Am I missing something?

Comment: What specifically are you trying to learn about this hypothetical system by conducting the experiment? You presumably already have the bacteria available in pure culture. That's what the plaques are forming on. If the phage are lytic then the infected bacteria are mostly lysed by the time plaques form.

Comment: make the PCR primer only bind to DNA found in the bacteria?

Comment: I think you may be confusing some of the terms.  On can only see, or visualize a phage plaque, if you have added an aliquot of infective phage to a growing bacterial culture, and then mixed that together with molten agar in the pour plate method.  As the bacterial lawn grows, the plaques are where the phage particles are either killing (lytic growth, like phage T4), or retarding (non-lytic growth like phage M13) bacterial growth.  If you are growing lytic phage and there are bacteria in the plaque, then those are bacteria that are resistant to that phage.

Comment: Some phage, like phage lambda, are capable of lysogenic growth, so they are integrated into the host chromosome like a hitch hiker and are basically dormant, until they are induced.  Depending on growth conditions, after induction they can grow lytically.  If you add lysogenic phage to a bacterial lawn, then the resulting plaques are said to be turbid, because there are some immune bacteria, growing in the middle of the plaques (i.e., lysogens).

Comment: Electrophoresis will separate DNA by size.